# PHP Laravel Database: Get all entries from one table + more

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My problem is a bit abstract, so I can't really explain.

I have a few tables: table 1 is called `videos` and the other tables are categories like Dell, HP, Acer etc.

In table 1 are videos which have *auto_increment* primary ID's `1,2,3,4` etc.
Video number 1 is from Dell, number 2 is HP, number 3 is Dell again and 4 is Acer.
Number 1 is also in table Dell as id 1, number 2 is in table HP as id 2, number 3 is in table Dell with id 3, and 4 is in acer as id 4.

```
public function showCategory($cat) {
    switch ($cat) {
        case 'dell':
            $dell = DB::table('dell')->get();
            $videoid = '';

            foreach ($dell as $video) {
                $videoid .= $video->videoid.',';
            }

            echo $videoid; // this is an echo (test)

            $videos = DB::table('videos')
                ->where('id', $videoid)
                ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(25);
            break;

        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

    return view('index')->with(array('videos' => $videos));
}
```

At this point, the echo $videoid; will show me all id's like:

```
1,3,40,42,43,44,46,58,61,67,68,73,86,101,102,103,105,106,112,117,121,122,123,124,
```

(i have many entrys)

The problem is, that on the index page it only shows number 1. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Put var_dump($videos); above the return and show what will be an output

Comment: did. it just output the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereIn` for multiple ids and explode method to make array of ids

```
        echo $videoid; // this is an echo (test)
        $videoArray = explode("," , $videoid);
        $videos = DB::table('videos')->whereIn('id', $videoArray)->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(25);
        break;
```

**Update** :

You can also use simple join

```
    $videos = DB::table('videos as v')
            ->join('dell as d','d.videoid','=','v.id')
            ->orderBy('v.id', 'DESC')
            ->select('v.*')
            ->paginate(25);
    break;
```

Remove all other code inside case `dell`

Comment: `$videoArray = $dell->pluck('videoid');` - no need for the `$videoid` string.